# Split Pandas Dataframe Column According To a Value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I searched and I couldn't find a problem like mine. So if there is and somehow I couldn't find please let me know. So I can delete this post.

I stuck with a problem to split pandas dataframe into different data frames (df) by a value.

I have a dataset inside a text file and I store them as `pandas dataframe` that has only one column. There are more than one sets of information inside the dataset and a certain value defines the end of that set, you can see a sample below:

**The Sample Input**

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
  var1
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    endValue
5    h
6    f
7    b
8    w
9    endValue
```

So I want to split this df into different data frames. I couldn't find a way to do that but I'm sure there must be an easy way. The format I display in sample output can be a wrong format. So, If you have a better idea I'd love to see. Thank you for help.

**The sample output I'd like**

```
  var1
{[0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    endValue]},
{[0    h
1    f
2    b
3    w
4    endValue]}
```

Comment: _I have a dataset inside a text file and I store them as pandas dataframe that has only one column._ Might it be possible to change how to data is parsed to get the correct format? Can you share some of the data?

Comment: I shared sample input data and expected output data on my question and actually, I found a good way to solve it. Below you can see. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check where `var1` is `endValue`, take the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), and use the result as a custom grouper. Then [`Groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and build a dictionary from the result:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.var1.eq('endValue').cumsum().shift(fill_value=0.))))
```

Or for a list of dataframes (effectively indexed in the same way):

```
l = [v for _,v in df.groupby(df.var1.eq('endValue').cumsum().shift(fill_value=0.))]
```

---

```
print(l[0])

       var1
0         a
1         b
2         c
3         d
4  endValue
```

Answer (score 3):

One idea with unique index values is replace non matched values to NaNs and backfilling them, last loop `groupby` object for list of `DataFrame`s:

```
g = df.index.to_series().where(df['var1'].eq('endValue')).bfill()
dfs = [a for i, a in df.groupby(g, sort=False)]
print (dfs)
[       var1
0         a
1         b
2         c
3         d
4  endValue,        var1
5         h
6         f
7         b
8         w
9  endValue]
```